# Error pops up when trying to start a vm in virtmanager

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I'm using [this](https://github.com/kholia/OSX-KVM) repository as a guide to virtualizing on Ubuntu 20.04. The virtualized OS is Catalina 10.15.4.

Error pops up when I try to open virtmanager and start the VM I created. Also when i try to use the `Opencore-boot.sh` option, the option to install the MacOS X won't show up.

***Error Log:***

```
Error starting domain: operation failed: unable to find any master var store for loader: /home/OSX-KVM/OVMF_CODE.fd

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 75, in cb_wrapper
   callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 111, in tmpcb
   callback(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/libvirtobject.py", line 66, in newfn
   ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/domain.py", line 1279, in startup
   self._backend.create()
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 1234, in create
   if ret == -1: raise libvirtError ('virDomainCreate() failed', dom=self)
libvirt.libvirtError: operation failed: unable to find any master var store for loader: /home/OSX-KVM/OVMF_CODE.fd
```

Comment: @K7AAY I am using ubuntu 20.04

Comment: on ubuntu trying to virtualize mac

Comment: Hi, this looks a bit like a case of uncommon paths. The loader is in a path that might be blocked. Please check if you see any apparmor denials in `dmesg` when trying to start your guest. If you do please see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LibvirtApparmor#Using_uncommon_paths